# URL masking (?in .htaccess) from one domain to another

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've been searching the archives but I can't find anything that is making too much sense to me.
I have a site with a couple of subdomains which redirect to other sites.

E.g.
the visitor types - [www.jmp.redtwenty.com.au](http://www.jmp.redtwenty.com.au) - and is redirected to - http://creator.zoho.com/redtwenty/jmp-conversion-tracking

Is there any way to mask this redirect so that the visitor still sees jmp.redtwenty.com.au in the address bar?

I keep seeing mention of a rewrite rule in .htaccess but not sure if that is what I want.

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 1):

You can do this a few ways, but you'll need to make sure mod_proxy is enabled.

If you have control of the server config or the vhost config of the `www.jmp.redtwenty.com.au/` domain, you can add this to it:

```
ProxyPass / http://creator.zoho.com/redtwenty/jmp-conversion-tracking/
```

Or in the htaccess file in the document root of `http://www.jmp.redtwenty.com.au/`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://creator.zoho.com/redtwenty/jmp-conversion-tracking/$1 [L,P]
```